# How to hook up pagination support to ArrayController?

Tags: ember.js

I'm attempting to use the `pagination_support` found [here](https://gist.github.com/tchak/1559628). Problematically, beyond hooking the `Mixin` into my `ArrayController`, I have not figured out how to get the `Mixin` to page the `content` of my `ArrayController`.

Anyone have any experience with making this work, who can help me get this settled?